# How to save non-English characters in text file in R?

Tags: r, unicode

I'm trying to save some text in hindi language to a text file in R.

```
data <- c("चौपाई")
write(data, "data.txt")
```

The output file data.txt when opened shows Unicode characters as -

```
<U+091A><U+094C><U+092A><U+093E><U+0908>
```

instead of the hindi text `चौपाई`

What am I doing wrong here?

Screenshot of Rstudio

[image]

screenshot when `data.txt` is opened in Windows Notepad

[image]

Screenshot when `data.txt` is opened in `Notepad +++`

[image]

Comment: You don't need to do anything, except perhaps specify the encoding, as your question proves. Those aren't Unicode characters at all, those are the way R displays them. This page is Unicode, which is why hindi is visible and I can write `Αυτό Εδώ` without resorting to escape sequences

Comment: If I do this with `RStudio 1.4`,  the output file looks good. Maybe you just need to update your RStudio to latest build?

Comment: How *did* you open that file? Did you check it with a text editor like `nano`? Or displayed it in RStudio? R and RStudio took a Loooooooooooong time to add proper Unicode support and still display escape sequences, eg in the debugger window, instead of the actual characters, unless you change settings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I also checked.  The file as `data` is displayed correctly in Rstudio, but after saving it as data.txt to local directory and when opened in any notepad (I tried in windows notepad, notepad+++, ted notepad) is not opened correctly.  Even when trying to read data.txt from Rstudio, the file is not displayed correctly

Comment: @AnilGoyal what does `is not opened correctly` mean? Garbled? With extra bytes? It matters. Extra characters means the file was saved as UTF8 without a Byte-Order-Mark (BOM) so the editors don't know it's UTF8 and display it using the system's locale. All editors allow you to display the text as UTF8 from a menu. Garbled means R saved the text using the system locale's codepage. One of R's quirks is that sometimes it uses the system locale instead of UTF8 on Windows, unlike other languages like C# or Java. Which is bit ... quirky, as Windows is a Unicode OS (all strings are UTF16) unlike Linux

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am adding screenshots in OP's question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround in the [Write file as UTF-8 encoding in R for Windows](https://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows/) article (with thorough explanation there):

```
BOM <- charToRaw('\xEF\xBB\xBF')

writeUtf8 <- function(x, file, bom=F) {
  Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"                  # superabundant?
  con <- file(file, "wb")
  if(bom) writeBin(BOM, con, endian="little")
  writeBin(charToRaw(x), con, endian="little")
  close(con)
}

data <- c("चौपाई")
writeUtf8(x=data, file="data.txt")
```

**Explanation** (*copy & paste* from abovementioned article, partially truncated):

> **Difference between Windows and other OSs**
>
> I am trying to say as simple as I can. The Windows chooses one of many
> language sets, however, the Linux and the Mac OS choose one language
> subset of a UTF-8 set. By this difference, the Windows forgets
> characters of unselected languages, while other OSs remember
> characters of all languages.
>
> **Problem on Windows**
>
> When a text is written to a file, characters of unselected locale
> languages can not be handled. Some of them are converted into a
> similar (but incorrect!) character, and others are written as escaped
> format such as <U+222D>.
>
> Mind that the R is not responsible for this problem. Because the OS’s
> architecture of switching languages is generating the problem.
>
> … when the R writes a UTF-8 text into a file on Windows, characters of
> unsupported language are modified. In contrast, all characters are
> written correctly in Mac OS.
>
> **Using binary**
>
> There is a solution for this problem. Writing a binary file instead of
> a text file solves this. All applications handling a UTF-8 file in
> Windows are using the same trick.
>
> **BOM**
>
> The BOM should not be used in UTF-8 files.  This is what the Linux and
> the Mac OS are doing. But the Windows Notepad and some applications
> use the BOM. So, handling the BOM is needed, in spite of grammatically
> wrong.
>
> The BOM is the 3 bytes character put at the beginning of a text file,
> but because the R does not use the BOM, it should be removed on
> reading.
>
> ```
> BOM <- charToRaw('\xEF\xBB\xBF')
> ```
>
> **Write UTF-8 file**
>
> ```
> writeUtf8 <- function(x, file, bom=F) {
>   con <- file(file, "wb")
>   if(bom) writeBin(BOM, con, endian="little")
>   writeBin(charToRaw(x), con, endian="little")
>   close(con)
> }
> ```
>
> Specify a UTF-8 string as x=, and a file name to write as file=. If
> you want to read the file only with the Windows Notepad, adding a BOM
> by the `bom=T` option is a good choice. Note that this is a minimum
> script, and not meant to write a very large file.

### Edit

Please note the *encoding* stuff (`Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8"`) added to both `readUtf8` and `readUtf8Text` functions:

> Reading a UTF-8 is easy, because functions like readLines have
> encoding= options   that accepts UTF-8.

```
readUtf8Text <- function(file) {
  con <- file(file, 'rt')
  result <- readLines(con, encoding='utf-8')
  close(con)
  Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8"                # important
  result
}
```

> If you want to read a UTF-8 file saved by Windows standard
> applications like Notepad, you may have a trouble. Because the Windows
> Notepad appends BOM at writing a UTF-8 file, you must remove the BOM
> on the R. Or the BOM will appear as a corrupted character at the
> beginning of the string.
>
> Now, the R 3.0.0 supports UTF-8-BOM encoding to remove the BOM.
> However, if you want to use R 2.15.3 for a while, you must remove the
> BOM manually. The following code reads a UTF-8 file as binary and
> remove the BOM.
>
> Note that this is a minimum script, and not meant to read a very large
> file.

```
readUtf8 <- function(file) {
  size <- file.info(file)$size
  con <- file(file, "rb")
  x <- readBin(con, raw(), size, endian="little")
  close(con)
  pstart <- ifelse(all(x[1:3]==BOM), 4, 1)
  pend <- length(x)
  result <- rawToChar(x[pstart:pend])
  Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8"               # important
  result
}
```

### Result

Tested in `RStudio` 1.3 as well as in `RGui` 4.0.1 (`Windows 10/64bit, i.e. platform` x86_64-w64-mingw32`):

```
> data <- c("चौपाई")
> writeUtf8(x=data, file="data.txt")
> 
> data
[1] "चौपाई"
>
> readUtf8Text(file="data.txt")
[1] "चौपाई"
>
> readUtf8(file="data.txt")
[1] "चौपाई"
```

To demonstrate importance of `Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8"` in both *read* functions for preventing [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
> file <- "data.txt"
> con <- file(file, 'rt')
> result <- readLines(con, encoding='utf-8')
> close(con)
> result                                       # mojibake
[1] "à¤šà¥Œà¤ªà¤¾à¤ˆ"
> Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8"
> result
[1] "चौपाई"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is an interesting read. Write to file now works fine as mentioned in the answer and article. I tried reading the same file but failed by both the methods (as given in the linked article). As an another workaround for the question, I tried changing locale within R, but there is no valid `LC_CTYPE` locale name available for `Hindi` language. Can you please check if reading file in R (as mentioned in the linked article) works at your end?

Comment: Read and write both works, now. I tested on a large data file (few thousand character only), in a `write` - `read` - `write` cycle for the same data . The checksum of first and second write matches without `mojibake`. I also learned about the word `mojibake`. Thanks for your kind help.